# Let code written for avoiding duplicates in r-dataframe only run within certain variable

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, nlp, data-science

With everyones help, I came up with some code to delete duplicate sentences from a dataframe, by first numbering all rows, then splitting into strings at sings that suggests the end a sentence, after that assigning the numbers to those newly split rows so that then I can take out all duplicate sentences by aggregating. After finishing that cleaning of all duplicates, some rows might have gone missing completely, since they were complete duplicates in the first place, which is why, before swapping the new cleaned posts with the old posts that had duplicates, I have to make sure that the vector with the new and cleaned posts has the same length as the old variable, which is why I "fill up" the rows that have gone missing using data.table:

```
    #Creating data for an example: 

    names <- c("Testperson", "Richard", "Mortimer", "Elizabeth", "Mortimer","Testperson2", "Tim", "Michel", "Random repeater", "Tim", "Dario", "Simko", "Paxi")

    posts <- c("This is a testsentence.", "I'm trying to find a solution for a problem with my neighbour, she keeps mowing the lawn on sundays when I'm trying to sleep in from my night shift.", "Personally, I like to deal with annoying neighbours by just straight up confronting them. Don't shy away. There are always ways to work things out!", "Personally, I like to deal with annoying neighbours by just straight up confronting them. Don't shy away. There are always ways to work things out! That sounds quite aggressive. How about just talking to them in a friendly way, first?", "That sounds quite aggressive. How about just talking to them in a friendly way, first? Didn't mean to sound aggressive, rather meant just being straightforward, if that makes any sense.", "This is a testsentence.", "Hey you losers.", "Hey you losers. Stop calling us that.", "Hey you losers.", "Stop calling us that. No, stop whining.", "Nah man, I think Michel's got a point.", "Nah man, I think Michel's got a point. I think so, too. Just became kinda lame and inappropriate after some time.", "Guys, chill.")

    forum <- c("gardening", "gardening", "gardening", "gardening", "gardening","casualchat", "casualchat", "casualchat", "casualchat", "casualchat", "casualchat", "casualchat", "casualchat")

    frame1 <- data.frame(names, posts, forum)

    #Code I came up with:

    counter <- c(1:13)

    frame1_og <- cbind(frame1, counter)

    frame1 <- strsplit(as.character(frame1_og$posts), "(?<=[.?!])(?=.)", perl=TRUE)

    frame1 <- lapply(frame1, trimws)

    frame1 <- stack(setNames(frame1, frame1_og$counter))

    frame1 <- data.frame(aggregate(values ~ ind, data=frame1[!duplicated(frame1$values),], FUN=paste, collapse=" "))

    library(data.table)

    frame1$ind <- as.numeric(frame1$ind)

    finalframe <- setDT(frame1)[CJ(ind = seq(min(ind), max(ind))), on = "ind"]

    frame1_og$posts <- finalframe$values

    View(frame1_og)
```

Now, this whole process works just fine, but would work even more accurately if I took into account the variable "forum" which indicates the different chat-rooms the data stems from. I wan't to achieve the whole deletion process I have just described but this time, I want the deletion of duplicates to take place on subgroups, indicated by the different values of the variable 'forum', so that the sentence "This is a testsentence." won't be deleted anymore and my output looks like this:

```
     frame1_og[6,2] <- "This is a testsentence."
```

Comment: I am assuming `frame1` is your input. What output do you expect ?

Comment: Thats kind of the problem here. The frame1_og as it stands in the last line is the output I'm expecting, except that the counter variable would start from 1 when 'casualchat' begins. But I'm not really sure since I don't know if the way I'm imagining is the right way to go here.

Comment: And yes, frame1 is my input. What I basically want to achieve is to let the code run for splits of the data, where the variable 'forum' is used for splitting, and then in the end bind them back together.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being imprecise, I just have a hard time thinking of possible approaches.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are looking but it does start the counter at 1 when "casualchat" begins. Using `dplyr`, `frame1_og %>%
  group_by(forum) %>%
  mutate(counter1 = row_number())`

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for the help, but this way not what I'm looking for. I basically look for some way to get the whole "duplicate cleaning", which right now cleans duplicates without respecting the boundaries of the posts, to clean duplicates but respect boundaries of the post. Imagine the forum variable has many many different groups, now I iteratively want to split the dataframe into groups that have all the same value on 'forum', run my code on each group, and then bind them all together.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve with your first code as well. Could you please provide some information for the whole process?

Comment: @NpT Sure, should I just put it on the comment or in the question?

Comment: @psyph The question so as more people to understand and try to help. Thanks.

Comment: @RonakShah I edited the question. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a peace of code that I think will do what you want. Since you use data.table, I took the liberty to change some portions of your example, to work with data.table. I hope this helps. Check also my comments in the code:

```
library(data.table)



#Creating data for an example: 
names <- c("Testperson", "Richard", "Mortimer", "Elizabeth", 
"Mortimer","Testperson2", "Tim", "Michel", "Random repeater", "Tim", "Dario", 
"Simko", "Paxi")
posts <- c("This is a testsentence.", "I'm trying to find a solution for a problem with my neighbour, she keeps mowing the lawn on sundays when I'm trying to sleep in from my night shift.", "Personally, I like to deal with annoying neighbours by just straight up confronting them. Don't shy away. There are always ways to work things out!", "Personally, I like to deal with annoying neighbours by just straight up confronting them. Don't shy away. There are always ways to work things out! That sounds quite aggressive. How about just talking to them in a friendly way, first?", "That sounds quite aggressive. How about just talking to them in a friendly way, first? Didn't mean to sound aggressive, rather meant just being straightforward, if that makes any sense.", "This is a testsentence.", "Hey you losers.", "Hey you losers. Stop calling us that.", "Hey you losers.", "Stop calling us that. No, stop whining.", "Nah man, I think Michel's got a point.", "Nah man, I think Michel's got a point. I think so, too. Just became kinda lame and inappropriate after some time.", "Guys, chill.")

forum <- c("gardening", "gardening", "gardening", "gardening", "gardening","casualchat", "casualchat", "casualchat", "casualchat", "casualchat", "casualchat", "casualchat", "casualchat")

frame1 <- data.frame(names, posts, forum)



#frame1 as data table
setDT(frame1)






# Creating the index in the input data.table
frame1[,ind:=.I]



#Keeping only the index and the posts
frame1_og <- frame1[,.(ind,posts)]



#Spliting to sentenses
sentences <- strsplit(as.character(frame1_og$posts), "(?<=[.?!])(?=.)", perl=TRUE)

#removing white spaces
sentences <- lapply(sentences, trimws)


# adding the appropriate index in sentences
sentences <- stack(setNames(sentences, frame1_og$ind))



# making it data.table
setDT(sentences)
# changing the ind to integer from factor
sentences[,ind:=as.integer(ind)]

# merging with the input frame
frame1<-merge(frame1,sentences,by='ind')



 #create a flag showing the duplicated values within each forum group
 frame1[,duplicate:=duplicated(values),by=forum]

 #keeping only the non duplicated values in the finalframe 
 finalframe<-frame1[duplicate==FALSE,]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the great work, definitely cleaned up the code and helped, but there is still some issue with the last line. The output doesn't contain the sentence 'This is a testsentence.' twice, which it should. Also, I'm required to have the length of the output match the length of the input and to not loose exact order.

Comment: @psyph I have updated the last part of the code to keep the correct non duplicates within each forum. Could you please explain why the order and especially the input /output length match is required?